# Trouble with finding odd and even index values for characters

Tags: java, security, encryption, password-encryption

I'm creating simple encryption/decryption software as a fun project. I am able to encrypt. It gives me the encrypted password and the key. The problem I'm having is in the decryption. For an example, here is an encrypted message: eUwG:Q_vul=u^CMiojpnif and here is the key: 103141109141719141119050117050318040907010912. The way it works is by first adding a random salt to the beginning or end of the message which is defined by the first number in the key. So since the first number is 1 then the salt is at the beginning (the salts are 14 characters long), so it removes that text, leaving Miojpnif. In the key after the salt number, there are 2 numbers per letter in the text. which is where I'm stuck. A number 1 means that the character was shifted forward, and 0 means backwards. So for the 'M' in the key for that character it's 0 so it was shifted backwards and the next number is 3 meaning that it was shifted backwards by 3. So to reverse this I need to shift that character forward 3. The thing is, I can't figure out how to make this work properly. My idea is that it removes the first number (salt) from the key, and then if the number is odd, then it records if the character will go forward or back, and if it's even then it'll move that character forward or back (which is stored as an int like the rest) by that number. So where I'm stuck is that figuring out if it's even or odd isn't working properly and I can't quite figure out how to shift that character.

I already looked up how to figure out if it's even or odd, but it still doesn't work. Actually shifting the character I made up my own code for. I don't know if you guys understand what I need help with because I didn't really know how to express it in words. So here is the code that I have, I hope that y'all can help.

```java
for(int i= 0; i < keyNew.length(); i++){
    if(i % 2 == 1){
        /*odd*/
        if(keyNew.charAt(i) == '1') {
        forward = 1;
        backward = 0;
        } else {
        forward = 0;
        backward = 1;
        }
    }else{
        /*even*/
    if(forward == 1 && backward == 0) {
        /*forward*/
        System.out.println("forward");
        String encryptedNewer = encryptedNew.charAt(i / 2) += keyNew.charAt(i);
    } else if(forward == 0 && backward == 1) {
        *backward*/
        System.out.println("backward");
        String encryptedNewer = encryptedNew.charAt(i / 2) += keyNew.charAt(i);
    }
     }
}
```

encrypted is the encrypted text, key is the key, encryptedNew is the text without the salt and keyNew is the key without the first digit.

Comment: When you "shift M" backward by 3 what do you get? It isn't clear based on your description.  Also, your `Miojpnif` is 8 characters long but you have 22 pairs of digits.  Am I missing something?

Comment: He can remove the salt of the encrypted message, what by definition isn't a salt. The salt is 14 chars long.

Comment: Ok.  I got it.  You had to decrypt the salt which didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of the long method smell. I recommend the following:

- Work with String and use the substring(...) function. It is easier, because you need less variables and don't have to convert from char to int and back.
- Create a function encrypt(...) and decrypt(...) which calls some "subfunctions"
- One subfunction is addSalt(...) and removeSalt(...)
- One subfunction is splitKeyToPairs(...) which returns a List of strings with 2 Digits per Item.
- One subfunction is shiftForward(...) and shiftBackwards(...)

Then I would implement it as follow:

```
public String decrypt(String key, String cipher) {
       String cipherModified = removeSalt(key, cipher);
       List<String> keyPairs = splitKeyToPairs(key.substring(1, key.length()));
       String message = "";
       for(int position = 0; position < keyPairs.size();++position) {
         String keyTmp = keyPairs.get(position);
         String cipherLetter = cipherModified.substring(position, position + 1);
         message += "0".equals(keyTmp.substring(0, 1)) ? shiftBackwards(cipherLetter, keyTmp.substring(1, 2)) : shiftForward(cipherLetter, keyTmp.substring(1, 2));
       }

       return message;  
    }

    public List<String> splitKeyToPairs(String key) {
      List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i += 2) {
        //i += 2 because we jump 2 characters per iteration.
        result.add(key.substring(i, i+2));
      }

      return result;
    }
```

Here a little test function for the split but not for the decrypt:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result = splitKeyToPairs("1234567890");
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12", "34", "56", "78", "90"));

        for(int i = 0; i < result.size();++i) {
            if(!result.get(i).equals(test.get(i))) {
                System.out.println("error on position " + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i think that this will help a lot. it's just im pretty new to java. (not coding in general)

Comment: Also, thank you for understanding my problem, I wasn't exactly sure how to express it.

Comment: That's ok. I started the same way. :)

Comment: May you want improve your skills with the Gang of Four Pattern book and the Code Smell book of fowler. You will find many free summaries and explanations for example here https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is another approach to decrypting the message.  Establishing methods and tucking them away in a library would be advisable.  In the following example I omitted the salt digit from the key.  The logic to accommodate that is trivial.

```java
      String key = "03141109141719141119050117050318040907010912";
      String code = "eUwG:Q_vul=u^CMiojpnif";
      int i = 0;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int pos = 0; pos < code.length(); pos++) {
         // get codeLetter
         char codeLetter = code.charAt(pos);
         // set direction
         int direction = key.charAt(i++) == '0' ? 1
               : -1;
         // set count
         int count = key.charAt(i++) - '0';
         // modify codeLetter based on direction and count
         char c = (char) (codeLetter + (count * direction));
         // save it.
         sb.append(c);
      }
      System.out.println(sb.toString().substring(14));
```